# Entity Framework 4.2 Code First DBMS support

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

What DB Management Systems does EF 4.2 Code First support?
I'd like to use Code First with MySQL and Oracle. Do I have to download extra things?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It supports the most of the popular DBMS's like Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite other than SQL Server. Yes you have to download database connectors for them. [Here](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html) is a good tutorial to get you started.